# How to create a Library/Framework that will be linked and used only if present at compile time

Tags: ios, ios6

I'm interested in replicating the sort of functionality that you see with Apple frameworks: where Apps can take advantage of new frameworks on more recent versions of iOS but don't fail when they're missing.

Of course if there's another approach to solving the problem I'd love to see it.

---

The position I'm in is as follows:

Company-A provides an iOS framework (hereafter named FrameA) to third parties that they can link into their Apps.

I am tasked with creating an optional module that can be "bolted on" to FrameA, but isn't actually a part of it (this is due to FrameA often being updated and customized for different customers and other business limitations).

The third parties can choose to use the bolt-on library (or framework, or whatever will work) or not. If it is present FrameA must link it and the code execute it's functionality. If it is not present then FrameA continues as it does now. It must work for third parties that receive new versions of FrameA but not the bolt-on library.
I should make as few changes to FrameA as possible since those changes will have to be maintained going forwards by another team.

I also need to do this within Apples submission rules, the solution must support at least iOS6, 7 and 8. So Dynamic linking is not allowed.
Company-A provides FrameA directly to the third-parties, so the only part that Apple has to approve is the final App.

Comment: Does FrameA have to call into the bolt-on or is the flow of control always from bolt-on to FrameA?

Comment: @JefferyThomas App -> FrameA --(is-bolt-on-present?)--> bolt-on. The App drives it, but the App isn't allowed to talk to the bolt-on directly.  I'm not very experienced with linking on iOS/ObjC, I was thinking about proposing that FrameA include a dummy bolt-on that just returns a "no functionality here message", and then for the third-parties that want the bolt-on it can be swapped out for a fully-featured one. But I'm concerned about Apple's approval for that. I'd also love to hear if anyone has a way of doing it that wouldn't provide anything superfluous to those who don't want it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this kind of thing on a small scale, and it's not too bad.

From within FrameA, use a factory to instantiate all bolt-on objects. The factory uses `NSClassFromString()` to dynamically fetch the class. Avoid class methods: this makes things harder. Whenever possible, use protocols instead of classes: this makes things easier.

```
- (id<FABoltOnProtocol>)createBoltOnClass
{
    return [[NSClassFromString(@"BOBoltOnClass") alloc] init];
}
```

This code will run even if `BOBoltOnClass` is not linked into the final app. `NSClassFromString(@"BOBoltOnClass")` will return `Nil`, `[Nil alloc]` returns `nil`, and `[nil init]` returns `nil`.

You can test for bolt-on's existence the same way.

```
BOOL MyHasBoltOn
{
    return NSClassFromString(@"BOBoltOnClass") != Nil;
}
```

The drawback is FrameA must be compiled with the headers from bolt-on. This is why I recommended protocols. These protocols can be owned by FrameA and bolt-on will conform to it (NOTE: I hinted at this by naming the protocol with FrameA's prefix FA and the class with bolt-on's prefix BO).

Finally, being a string, you can read @"BOBoltOnClass" from a config file so you can swap different bolt-ons as needed.

*Be aware that the build flag -ObjC must be set, as otherwise the compiler will not load symbols for the bolt-on classes as they're not called conventionally.*

Comment: This may well be exactly what I'm after, just to clarify: as long as the bolt-ons maintain the same header structure we could change up the functionality without having to recompile frameA? Just change the bolt-on library and recompile the App?

Comment: @Ian yes, linking in the final app is what puts all the functionality together.

Comment: @Ian No idea. Post an example as a new question.

Comment: nevermind, I had a little code blindness to simple mistake. It works fine.